# Spring class not found for maven project in Windows XP

Tags: java, windows, maven

I'm running a maven project (.jar file) on Windows with `java -jar "/path-to-jar/myfile.jar"` and it can't find `org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

Do I need to add the dependencies like spring into the `<build>` portion of the pom.xml or something to be sure these are included in the .jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to find, but Maven build plugins are what I needed....

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.production.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tar-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.production.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <finalName>myapp</finalName>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would not be including library jars in your application jar (without using a custom classloader or [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)). Instead, set the `-classpath` java command line argument with `:`-delimited jar files that you've used to compile/build your jar file. So your command would look like

```
java -classpath .:lib/spring.jar:lib/spring-context.jar:lib/others.jar -jar "/path-to-jar/myfile.jar"
```